# How do i turn layer visibility off for specific layers in a .PSD file using image magick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, photoshop, psd, mogrify

I am writing a program to check layer visibility on specific layers and if they are visible turn the visibility off. I have all of it working except for being able to turn the layers off. In order to do so I am trying to use image magick version 6.8.8.

In my attempts to figure this out I have found that it seems the Compose attribute of the layers is responsible for determining the visibility of the layer. When the layers are turned on the compose value is 'Over' and if the layer is off Compose is set to 'None'. I tried using the following command to modify this value from over to none to turn the layers visibility off:

```
mogrify.exe -set compose None test.psd
```

The command appears to run fine, it doesn't throw any errors. However, when reopening the file it seems as though nothing changed. I have also tried adding in [layer#] to the end of the source file to operate on the specific layers I wanted to change and it still did not turn the layer off. In addition I have tried all manner of quoting both the parameter and the attribute name to no avail.

While I remain unable to turn the layer off I do seem to be able to turn a layer's visibility on. By using the command:

```
mogrify.exe +set compose test.psd
```

This command uses the +set operator which resets the specified attribute to its default value. In a PSD file layer visibility's default is on and running this command did appear to turn the layers that were off on as it is their default. So from what I can see this is an editable field but I can not seem to be able to change it in my attempts.

Does anyone know of an image magick command which will allow specific layers visibility to be toggled to off in a PSD file.

Comment: ImageMagick is a pixel processor and does not modify PS meta data or compose setting as far as I understand. Perhaps EXIFTOOL will do that, but I suspect you need a PS specific editor for that. To do that in ImageMagick, you would have to extract the two layers and recomposite them and then save again as PSD.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I would rather avoid having to recomposite the image so I will give EXIFTOOL a look. Thanks again.

Comment: This can be easily done with a Photoshop script (JavaScript). You could create an array of names to look for and switch them off as needed.

Comment: I am aware of that functionality. The main reason I was looking to do this with image magick or some other piece of software was because I need this to be done without having to actually have photoshop open when it runs. In other words I need something that can edit the .psd source file itself not use photoshop's built in actions/scripts.